# Radlistbox with large number of items throws exception on click of save button

Tags: asp.net, telerik-radlistbox

When I am clicking the save button on aspx, getting server side error 500 when my telerik radlist contains large number of items

I have tried changing the allowedMaxLength for query string in IIS and this works fine, but I do not want to make this change as it can compromise my site's security.

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>   occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>   returned from the server was: 500
>       at Function.Error$create [as create] (http://localhost/mysite/ScriptResource.axd?d=jWVTuxPq_njvedXvVPyYyX19UsW4XOYf9IQdlAjdeRLVRLRyHuCyeaI2j03JBiQeBm8DXaxoht8jIEXRALBKxfRkZcRQqVFwb8Hq3yWRC5NpDiVoTPAFxco9j-JV_ODRuX4t1XPZeC-lUYQthmCTShlZ8y09xUFrw3v2PpfN2CsSMiXT0&t=3f4a792d:222:13)
>       at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerServerError
>   [as _createPageRequestManagerServerError]
>   (http://localhost/mysite/ScriptResource.axd?d=q3C1Ct2cHsDgcSrZufDahBI3LVgo7qQQOowT39JZa6Vj_6WF4mGjYqHTeQ7SWQypht8_LJmtQjaDmeNAVTY7BasraYOPOrrCzpwM3Qd8_EHmERhKdN9l2JZ2kRghLEd3ESRxgOd5YDImY5z2wW9KyFBTLORpH_aVz_X4GRIbTnUw8D9c0&t=3f4a792d:360:23)
>       at Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted [as _onFormSubmitCompleted] (http://localhost/mysite/ScriptResource.axd?d=q3C1Ct2cHsDgcSrZufDahBI3LVgo7qQQOowT39JZa6Vj_6WF4mGjYqHTeQ7SWQypht8_LJmtQjaDmeNAVTY7BasraYOPOrrCzpwM3Qd8_EHmERhKdN9l2JZ2kRghLEd3ESRxgOd5YDImY5z2wW9KyFBTLORpH_aVz_X4GRIbTnUw8D9c0&t=3f4a792d:900:36)
>       at Array. (http://localhost/mysite/ScriptResource.axd?d=jWVTuxPq_njvedXvVPyYyX19UsW4XOYf9IQdlAjdeRLVRLRyHuCyeaI2j03JBiQeBm8DXaxoht8jIEXRALBKxfRkZcRQqVFwb8Hq3yWRC5NpDiVoTPAFxco9j-JV_ODRuX4t1XPZeC-lUYQthmCTShlZ8y09xUFrw3v2PpfN2CsSMiXT0&t=3f4a792d:47:23)

I want that when I click the save button, then on the postback event, I should be able to post all the list data without allowedMaximumLength exceeded message.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Load On Demand functionality of the RadListBox that would not load all the items of the client:

- Online demo - https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/functionality/loadondemand/defaultcs.aspx
- Documentation - https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/listbox/functionality/load-on-demand

Also, you can try some general performance optimization approaches such as:

- Disabling the ViewState of the control or saving it on the server;
- Using the RadScriptManager control on the page instead of the ScriptManager to combine scripts.
- Using the Lightweight render mode of the control